# Prevent IntelliJ IDEA from generating reports Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

So, I have pretty old MacBook with 8GB RAM.

Recently I started noticing that IDEA puts this type of files to the root directory that I accidentally committed :)

How it looks:

[image: ss]

Inside:

```
{
  "header": {
    "event": "Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory",
    "location": "OnFatalError",
    "filename": "report.20190403.174759.17867.001.json",
    "dumpEventTime": "2019-04-03T17:47:59Z",
    "dumpEventTimeStamp": "1554302879528",
    "processId": 17867,
    "commandLine": [
// else file
```

How may I disable this "feature"?

Thanks!

Comment: If the issue in committing such files you could easily filter them out from the git by `.gitignore` with `report*.json` row or something like that.
Note, that you should `uncommit` (git rm) old files, as they are already committed to the repo.

Comment: does the problem occur when you run your application, or just on editing code, etc.? Do you have any linters or Typescript language service enabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a `.gitignore` file at the root of the project which contents

```
report*.json
```

You should commit that file to the repo and remove `report` files that you've already committed to the repo.

Comment: Thanks, but that is not a solution for this problem

Comment: @NikitaShchypyplov Well, I do not think you can prevent IDEA from creating reports, as they are created for some reason (probably there is an issue with your js). Possibly you can say to IDEA where exactly you want these files. So far, ignoring them (as other idea configs) is the easiest solution.

Comment: @NikitaShchypyplov by isue with JS I mean memory leak at some point. Maybe it is related to js processor, not to code directly.

Answer (score 0):

**How to fix it for IntelliJ Idea:**

- in **Help** | **Find action**..., type **registry**
- open **Registry**, locate **typescript.service.node.arguments** key there (you can start typing property name to navigate to it)
- add **--max_old_space_size** option there (**--max_old_space_size=4096**, for example)

[JetBrains support link](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360003472280-JS-Heap-Out-of-Memory-WS-2019-1-1)